# counting the number of values in a linked list

Tags: python, python-2.7

There is something wrong with my `countInt` function. besides the fact that it is labelled countINT and im putting `'-'` in it as an argument. I tested the creation of my linked list and it seems to work properly. SO i feel that I can safely rule that out as an issue. However, with the NoneType object has no attribute value error, I'm not sure where I went wrong. Could someone be another set of eyes for me and help me pick out the error and guide me to correcting it? Thank you much appreciated!

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "linked_list.py", line 63, in <module>
    print countInt(r,1)
  File "linked_list.py", line 25, in countInt
    countInt(head.next,n)
  File "linked_list.py", line 25, in countInt
    countInt(head.next,n)
  File "linked_list.py", line 25, in countInt
    countInt(head.next,n)
  File "linked_list.py", line 25, in countInt
    countInt(head.next,n)
  File "linked_list.py", line 25, in countInt
    countInt(head.next,n)
  File "linked_list.py", line 25, in countInt
    countInt(head.next,n)
  File "linked_list.py", line 25, in countInt
    countInt(head.next,n)
  File "linked_list.py", line 25, in countInt
    countInt(head.next,n)
  File "linked_list.py", line 25, in countInt
    countInt(head.next,n)
  File "linked_list.py", line 25, in countInt
    countInt(head.next,n)
  File "linked_list.py", line 25, in countInt
    countInt(head.next,n)
  File "linked_list.py", line 25, in countInt
    countInt(head.next,n)
  File "linked_list.py", line 23, in countInt
    if head.next.value == n:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'
```

expected output:

```
2
2
```

my code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.next = None
        self.value = value

def createLinkedList(root, node):
    if root.next is None:
        root.next = node
    else:
        createLinkedList(root.next, node)

def countInt(head, n, count= 0):        #create a dictionary with keys as the values of the linked list and count up if the value occurs again
    count = 0
    if head.value is None:
        return None
    else:
        if head.next.value == n:
            count += 1
        countInt(head.next, n, count)
        return count


# root
r = Node(1)

# nodes
a = Node(4)
b = Node(1)
c = Node(5)
d = Node('-')
e = Node(4)
f = Node(1)
g = Node(2)
h = Node('-')
i = Node(8)
j = Node(9)
k = Node(8)
l = Node(3)

createLinkedList(r,a)
createLinkedList(r,b)
createLinkedList(r,c)
createLinkedList(r,d)
createLinkedList(r,e)
createLinkedList(r,f)
createLinkedList(r,g)
createLinkedList(r,h)
createLinkedList(r,i)
createLinkedList(r,j)
createLinkedList(r,k)
createLinkedList(r,l)


print countInt(r,1)
print countInt(r,'-')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line:

```
if head.value is None:
```

to

```
if head.next is None:
```

The purpose of the line is to know when the list should stop, at which point the next node will be `None`. The value stored in the node doesn't have anything to do with that: the last node will still have a value (and conversely, you might want to store the value `None` earlier in the list).

---

As a separate issue, your function will always return 0. The line `countInt(head.next, n, count)` doesn't actually do anything to the variable `count`: Python passes ints by value, so the variable you passed won't get incremented. And even once you fix that, the fact that you're always checking `head.next` means that you're skipping the first element in your list. You should instead set up your function as:

```
def countInt(head, n):
    count = 0
    if head.value == n:
        count = 1
    if head.next is None:
        return count
    return count + countInt(head.next, n)
```

This actually lets you get rid of passing `count` down through the list (which is an awkward way to implement recursion).

Comment: however, what if I were to enter in only one node that had the value n as its value?

Comment: @Liondancer: Great point: My suggested code was in the wrong order and wouldn't work in that case. Fixed.